# Nat Loopback - Access external IP from internal

Tags: web-server, router, nat, local-area-network, loopback

I have a static IP and I've made a webserver that is running fine from WAN (domain points to my IP).

However, when I access my external IP/Domain from my LAN, it redirects me to my router login page.

What can I do to fix this?

I've read something about editing the Windows `hosts` file, but what should I put in there?

```
xx.xx.xx.xx   mydomain.com (Should this do the job?)
```

Thanks!

**Setup: Huawei HG658 Router, Windows 10, BitNami WAMP Stack 7.0.22-1**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArFuy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use external IP to access to your server inside local network. Use server's  local IP address. Many operating systems (include Microsoft Windows) read `hosts` file before send DNS query to resolve domain name to IP address. That's why `x.x.x.x` must be server's IP address in your local network and `mydomain.com` must be full real domain name of your server (not local).